# try to get the first attributes from the 1st store in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, attributes

i'm trying to get the 1st store attributes, from a specific page,
until now, i can't reach it , because i think it's kind of an array of store - how can i get only the first one ?

```
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.zap.co.il/') as response:
html = response.read()
check ='https://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword='+'20KN0061IV'
r = requests.get(check)
html = requests.get(r.url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'xml')
price = bsObj.find('div',attrs={'class':'StoresLines'})
print(price)
```

im getting all the stores - but i want only the first store - how to do that ?

Comment: What's the point of the first request? Is it a health check?

Comment: i need all the data about the first store from the class ' StoresLines'  . the link is [link] https://www.zap.co.il/model.aspx?modelid=976556

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the top store (the store before the break) you can replace

```
price = bsObj.find('div',attrs={'class':'StoresLines'})
```

with:

```
price = bsObj.select_one('div.StoreLine')
```

If you wanted to get the top store from the bunch of lines below the break, replace the same line with:

```
price = bsObj.select_one('div.StoresLines div.StoreLine')
```

Hope this helps!

**Output of the last suggestion:**

```
<div class="StoreLine" data-distance="0" data-hit="-1240851152" data-iseilat="False" data-price-caption="מחיר סופי" data-prod-price="2609" data-product-id="688189532" data-siteid="1245" data-sog="c-pclaptop" data-store-line="" data-supply="2" data-total-price="2609" data-total-rank="4.48" pid="688189532">
<div class="StoreLine">
<div class="StoreLogo">
<a aria-label="לקריאת חוות דעת על שניידר" href="/clientcard.aspx?siteid=1245" id=""><img alt="שניידר" border="0" class="Logo" id="" src="https://img.zap.co.il/pics/imgs/nsite/newui/newssite-1245.gif"/></a>
</div>
<div class="StoreReviews">
<div class="BlueStars">
<span style="width: 99px;"></span>
</div>
<div class="StoreReviewsTxt">
<a aria-label="לקריאת 67 חוות דעת על Lenovo E480 20KN0061IV יבואן רשמי במלאי 1134 בסך הכל" class="LongLine" href="/clientcard.aspx?siteid=1245">67 חוות דעת בשנה האחרונה<br/>1134 בסך הכל</a>
</div>
<div class="StoreTags">
<div class="MapContainer1245 Regular" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="StoreInfo">
<div class="StoreTitle">
<div class="StoreName">
<div aria-label="למידע נוסף על Lenovo E480 20KN0061IV יבואן רשמי במלאי" class="InfoBtn" onclick="javascript:ShowStoreTooltip(this, 'Lenovo E480 20KN0061IV יבואן רשמי במלאי','מוצר חדש 20KN0061IV יצרן: Lenovo , סוג מוצר: מחשב נייד , דגם מעבד: Intel® Core™ i5-8250U Processor (6M Cache, up to 3.40 GHz), נפח זכרון פנימי: 8GB , נפח אחסון: 256GB , סוג דיסק: PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD , גודל מסך: 14.0 , רזולוציה: 1920x1080 , דגם כרטיס מסך:');"></div>
<a aria-label="לקנייה ב-שניידר Lenovo E480 20KN0061IV יבואן רשמי במלאי" class="hl_ProductTitle modelClick" href="/fs.aspx?pid=688189532&amp;sog=c-pclaptop" id="" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Lenovo E480 20KN0061IV יבואן רשמי במלאי</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ProdInfo">
<div class="infoItem">
<span class="label">מחיר:</span>
                        2,609 ₪
                    </div>
<div class="infoItem">
<span class="label">
                                משלוח:</span>
                            חינם
                        </div>
<div class="infoItem">
<span class="label">זמן אספקה:</span>
                            יומיים
                        </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="FinalPrice">
<div class="FinalPriceLabel">מחיר סופי:</div>
<div class="PriceNum">2,609 ₪ </div>
</div>
<div class="BuyButtons">
<a aria-label="לקנייה ב-שניידר Lenovo E480 20KN0061IV יבואן רשמי במלאי" href="/fs.aspx?pid=688189532&amp;sog=c-pclaptop" id="" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><div class="BuyBtn orange-style modelClick" rel="nofollow">
<div class="BuyBtnText">
                            לקנייה
                        </div>
</div></a>
<div class="BuyButtonsTxt">
                ב-<a aria-label="לקנייה ב-שניידר Lenovo E480 20KN0061IV יבואן רשמי במלאי" href="/fs.aspx?pid=688189532&amp;sog=c-pclaptop" id="" target="_blank">שניידר</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

where:

```
price.select_one('.FinalPrice .PriceNum').text
```

returns:

```
'2,609 ₪ '
```

Comment: thanks , but i'm getting all the stores. i need only the first store from the class 'StoresLines' . the link is [link] https://www.zap.co.il/model.aspx?modelid=976556

Comment: are you sure `bsObj.select_one('div.StoresLines div.StoreLine')` doesn't return what you're after?